# Should content from database be sanitized again

Tags: databases, validation

Suppose I save content into the database after sanitizing it. Is there still a need to sanitize it again when retrieving it? If yes, why?

Answer (score 3):

"Sanitize", by itself, is meaningless. There is no such thing as "dirty data" as opposed to "clean data". When people think of data being "sanitized", they really mean "data which has been verified to be in a format suitable for a *specific processing*". For instance, if the purpose of the data is to be embedded into some SQL statement, then "sanitation" of the data involves making sure that it contains none of the characters that the SQL parser will consider as special (typically, no quotes).

A better word is *validation*. Whenever you must use some data, and the data is "potentially hostile" (it could have been crafted at some point, more or less directly, by an attacker in order to trigger unwanted behaviour in your code), then the data must be verified to be appropriate for the intended processing. If you "saved content into the database after sanitizing it" then chances at that you made sure that the data was in proper format *for the purpose of storing it in the database*. Depending on the validation steps needed to ensure safe storage, and what you intend to do with the data when you retrieve it, then this may or may not be sufficient.

For instance, suppose that the data element is obtained as some characters from the user, and should be stored in the database. The data element is supposed to be a number. However, the database-storage thing only minds about "special characters" and thus sees no problem in storing "BozoWasThere" in the database. In that sense, the string was sanitized (and the storing went very fine) but it still not a number, so this would warrant for further sanitation after retrieving it.

---

The concept of "sanitized data" is a great source of confusion. It is some mantra that many developers ritually utter ("sanitize all things !") because it give them the feeling that they did something about security, without having to perform that most inconvenient action known as *thinking*. In the long term, this does not work well.